# java reference to the outer object from inner object

Tags: java

JAVA

```
public class A {
  string amountA;
  B b;
}

public class B {
  string amountB;

   public void setValue(String value) {
      amountB = value;
```

Also, I need to set amountA = value;. Is it possible? See main method

```
      }
}

... main(String... args) {
   A a = new A();
   B b = a.getB(); // b is a member of A
   b.setValue("25") // this should also change 'amountA' in object 'a' to '25'
}
```

Comment: Note that with how your curly brackets are, B is **not** an inner class of A.

Comment: please post all the source code. Is class B an inner class of class A?

Comment: this code won't compile

Comment: Apparently, "outer object" here does not refer to inner and outer classes, but to a class that contains an instance of another class (composition, not nested classes). Is that correct, OP?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Assume main() is inside another class C. A and B are independent classes ( not actual inner class ). The relation between A and B is using composition ( B instance is inside A ).

Answer (score 1):

If you need to set both `valueA` and `ValueB` to the same `value`, it makes more sense to have a setter in class `A` that would set both of them :

```
   public void setValue(String value) {
      amountA = value; 
      b.setValue(value);
   }
```

You can't access an instance of A from within an instance of B, since B is not an inner class of A. You can create an instance of B that is not related at all to any instance of A.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class A {

    public class B {
        string amountB;

        public void setValue(String value) {
            amountB = value;       
            amountA = value; // Using A.this.amountA
        }
    }

    string amountA;

    public B createB() {
        return new B(); // Provides A.this to the B instance.
    }
}

... main(String... args) {
    A a = new A();
    B b = a.createB(); // b is created inside A
    b.setValue("25") // this should also change 'amountA' in object 'a' to '25'
}
```

You can use an inner class.

The class itself should better create the instance, so that `A.this` is set into the `b`.

Alternatively

```
B b = a.new B();
```

But I never ever used that.

Inner classes are practical for a container element having access to its container class.

Another solution is to make a method in A with the B object as parameter or so.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to have A *derive* from B rather than *contain* an instance of B.  That way the valueA in an instance of A and the valueA in the instance of B associated with that instance of A are really the same variable.  You can also have data in A that isn't shared with B by declaring it in A. For example,

```
public class A extends B {
   public String amountAonly; // a string in A that's not in B
   public B getB() { return (B)this; } // typecast to treat A like B
}

public class B {
   public String amountA; // a string that's in both A and B
   public void setValue(String value) {
      amountA = value;
   }
}
...
   main(String[] args) {
       A a = new A();
       B b = a.getB(); // b is the B associated with a
       b.setValue("25"); // will also change 'amountA' in object 'a' to '25'
    }
```